# How much water does lucky bamboo need?

Tags: houseplants, watering, lucky-bamboo

I was recently given some decorative "lucky bamboo". It came with four shoots approximately 6-8 inches tall and 1/4' thick. They sit in a glass jar with a diameter of 4' and a height of 6'. The jar looks to be filled 3/4 with sand and 1/4 with rocks.

Just curious how much water I should be giving my lucky bamboo?

Comment: Very similar to this question http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/how-do-i-grow-bamboo-plants-indoors

Answer (score 2):

How much water was in the jar when you received it? Because lucky bamboo can adapt to grow in  straight water, sometimes with sand/rocks as a root anchorage/substrate. In that case, keep it filled to near the level of the top of the sand/rocks. You can't really overwater, when the plant is adapted to these conditions, except to fill it until it spills :), which of course you wouldn't do. Keep the plant in bright, filtered light (not direct sun, or low light) for best longevity, and keep it cool if possible (under 75 degrees F.) to keep the growth rate at a minimum. You want it to look good as long as possible, so slow, steady, healthy growth is the kind you want.

Answer (score -2):

I had one several years back and I would water mine once a week and it would be fine. It died when I moved, but it did fine with that much. I would water it about 1 cup and let it drain through the holes.